# is it possible read raw video data from v4l2 and transfer via mqtt to a service

Tags: linux, video-streaming, gstreamer, raspbian, v4l2

I want to capture video from webcam and rather creating a RTP stream I want it to send to a web service via mqtt. web-service will compress persist the video.

I came a cross v4l2 for capturing video/ raspivid in Raspberry pi,
and GStreamer for RTP streaming but I want to send it via mqtt

How can I build this application. what are the libraries I can make use?

Comment: Why do you want to use MQTT? What benefit do you think it will give to use a pub/sub protocol for this?

Comment: I am thinking that if I am using stream over HTTP it will consume more processing power. If I can transfer the raw data I can process it on a computer. It would be easier to run different image processing algorithms in different nodes with pub/sub protocol.

Comment: nah, with the proper format, RTP basically sends *raw* data; the container overhead is usually neglectible. before starting optimization you should profile your pipeline, to see where the processing power is consumed (rather than assuming that some random protocol will fix it for you)

Comment: My application really need pub/sub protocol. Any existing streaming protocols support this?